# update, delete of domain models

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I am using Spring, hibernate for my . For Update I call `repo.findById(id)` to get the current instance, thereafter call `model.setXXX()` to update fields and finally, `repo.save(mdl)` to save it back. For delete, I call `repo.remove(id)` , now both my update and delete are state-driven , and may bring about state change on my models and sometimes , based on the state, certain actions like delete are not allowed. How do i go about implementing those behaviour in such a way that this logic is essentially within the domain models and doesn't leak to repository implementation?

Comment: Some might say that the repository is part of the domain model (at least its interface). How you communicate deletion (which is a lousy term as this is hardly what anybody calls it) to persistent storage is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
// entity
class User{
  ...
  bool CanBeArchived(){
    // check whether objects can be archived based
    // on the rules and state that you mention
  } 
  ...
}

// repository
interface UserArchiver{
  // implementation calls 'CanBeArchived' and throws if it fails
  void Archive(User user)
}
```

You don't seem to like the approach outlined above because

> ... logic is essentially within the domain models and doesn't leak to
>   repository implementation

I don't think that you should be worried about domain leaking into repository implementation. This is unavoidable anyway, data access layer (repo implementation) has intimate knowledge of domain objects anyway, otherwise it would not be able to hydrate them. What you should be worried is a reverse - 'data access leaking into domain' and this is not happening in the code above.